# Multi host docker-compose with static internal IP for database

Tags: mysql, docker

I am fighting with this over 3 weeks.
I've tried numerous of tutorials but none of them worked for me.

Basically I have > 10 servers that are running Ubuntu + docker.

Some of them are accessible via internal IP, some via public IP.

I have connected all locations using VPN.

They all can reach each other via 10.0.0.0/8

Now I've tried to create MySQL database on each of a servers (please do not ask why, as this is a part of requirements and won't change).

Some of those will be Masters, some Slaves.

Server A can host 4 Master DB and 3 Slave (all are interconnecting).

Basically I want to create a MySQL servers with static internal IP (exposing ports via virtual IP is already done, but static internal IP is part of requirements, won't change no matter what).

Unfortunately I've tried to create virtual interface
i.e. on each server (each server would be having only 1 ip with exposed port)
10.0.4.1
10.0.4.2

Then I've created a network sqlnet
 docker network create  --subnet=10.0.4.0/16 sqlnet

Unfortunately for some reason the server with internal IP is simply disconnects from network after that (I can use 10.0.5.0 or something similar), I have to use ILO to remove the network.

To be honest it seems like I have to be doing something wrong. Most of tutorials is useless as either requires additional knowledge (my only knowledge is to use dotnet build and to deploy it on a linux, due to cost of MS SQL we have to check if MySQL is reliable option).

Basically I want to create docker-compose (was trying to use stack, but getting a lot of different issues due to networking or interfaces being out of a scope, etc. etc.) that will deploy MySQL and expose it for a replication to other servers within the same VPN network.

Anyone knows how to do it ???? For some that internal IP is a hell on Earth (using -p IP:port works fine for other web apps/web api's, but those don't need static internal ip).

Comment: Would you consider using docker-compose? It's very easy to set static ips in the yaml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was solved by creating new interface on Docker host

i.e.

10.0.4.1,

Then in Docker-compose 
ports:
  - '10.0.4.1:4000:3306'

And by using this the interface 10.0.4.1 is accessible through out whole subnet 10.0.0.0/8 and all devices can see the docker container as it would be separate server.